# How can I pass an escaped javascript string as an argument into windows command line?

Tags: javascript, windows, command-line, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm attempting to pass an argument to casperJS via command line. I'm executing something like

```
> casperjs ..\test.js " \' { function ( var ) \'     asdf"
```

This is loading the argument as multiple arguments

```
casper.cli.args[0] == "\'"
casper.cli.args[1] == "{"
casper.cli.args[2] == "function"
casper.cli.args[3] == "("
...
```

Notice it's a new arg everytime there's a space character - The double quotes I placed around the argument obviously don't work with the space character.

When I concat and print the arguments out I get

```
"\'{function(var)\'asdf"
```

Notice spaces all removed/truncated/whatever.

How can I escape my string so that my js app gets the actual string in 1 argument without dropping content?

Keep in mine that I need to also keep the escape integrity of the JS string I'm passing as it needs to be interpreted downstream.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this until now.. Do I never did get a solution to this. I ended up using a work around like reading from a file or something. Can't recall as this was months ago now. @Mayank

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want to do, if you want to get back a custom argument in your file :

Considering your command is : `casperjs test yourFile.js --customArgument=" \' { function ( var ) \'     asdf"`

You get back the content in your file like that : `var customArg = casper.cli.get('customArgument');`

This is not what you want?

Comment: This gives me a customArg value of only up until the first space character still - The issue is that space characters are being interpretted by command line or phantom/casper as the delimiter between args or something
Whichever way you write it
<casperjs test.js "custom arg value"> or 
<casperjs test.js --argName="custom arg value">
The space characters in the string cause the values to be set to only "custom", dropping space characters and placing "arg" and "value" in separate args.

Comment: I updated the question to be more clear. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Ha yes, you're right, can't you replace `space` by `_` in the command line and reconvert them in casper?

Comment: Any ideas on how I can handle whitespace space characters vs quoted space characters in this - Remember this string needs to be interpreted downstream. What if the arg is something like "there are whitespace spaces 'and quoted space chars that need to actually stay to be interpreted'"

Comment: Well, found nothing in the doc or git, sorry :(